# Sliding window detector stride - Object detection

Tags: artificial-intelligence, object-detection

If i have an image of width 512 and height 640 and I use a sliding window of width 48 and height 72, what should I do at the 'boundaries' of the image when the detector goes slightly out of bounds ? Do i ignore that region or it is okay to crop and run the classifier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few common ways to handle this.

1. Pad the boundary with zeros. Ideally pad it evenly on both sides.
2. Pad the boundary with repeated values at the edge.
3. Similar to 2., some tile the boundary with mirrored (i.e., flipped) version of the image and cut off the excess.
4. Ignore it. This leads to a smaller output.

The choice depends on your application and assumption(s) of your algorithm/model.

Since you are doing sliding window object detection, if your window is small enough then 1., 2., and 4 are good options. Try them and decide based on the results obtained on validation dataset.

Comment: Thanks ! Good to know the various options of dealing with such problems.